# HTML: Why does embedded audio sometimes fail to play?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, audio, https

I am experiencing some strange behavior of embedded audio (wav file) on HTML page.
I've got a page `https://server.com/listen-to-sound`, and a Wav file embedded in it via `<EMBED/>` tag, like this:

```
<embed src='https://server.com/path-to-sound' hidden="true" autostart="true" />
```

The page `https://server.com/listen-to-sound` is opened in IE 6 SP3 on machine#1 - the sound is played in the headphones.
The same page is opened on another machine(#2), with **exactly** same IE 6 SP3 version, privacy and proxy settings - there's no sound.

Totally, from 6 machines the sound is played on 2 and not played on 4. From these 4 machines, when the page `https://server.com/listen-to-sound` is opened in Opera, the sound is played.

I've triple-checked headphone connections, volume settings and other possible hardware and software driver issues: the problem is definitely in IE settings.

I've also checked `https://server.com/path.to.sound` URL - the 4 machnies that do not play sound fail to open this link, failing with an error like "Failed to download page".

Cleaning IE caches, temporary internet files, SSL certificate caches did not solve the problem either.

Googling gave me nothing special but old Flash trick to use `<OBJECT>` tag and `<EMBED>` tag to be written in Object's comments.

What have I missed? Have you experienced similar or related problems? How were they solved?
Do you have any suggestions on where the trick is? Do you know some IE "features" that might affect execution(playing, showing) of embedded objects?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main reason  is acting different on each computer/browser you're using is because it is a non-standard tag.

Getting media to play inside a web page has always been a bit of a pain. You may try something like this:

```
<object type="audio/x-wav" data="data/test.wav" width="200" height="20">
  <param name="src" value="data/test.wav">
  <param name="autoplay" value="false">
  <param name="autoStart" value="0">
  alt : <a href="data/test.wav">test.wav</a>
</object>
```

The above was taken from [this site](http://joliclic.free.fr/html/object-tag/en/) explaining how to use the object tag.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found the solution, but I can confirm that the likely problem is the https:. I have found that windows media player does not play files with a full url/src leading to https. However, quicktime will. So, computers with quicktime will successfully play the file back while those with only WMP will fail.

One "solution" is to link to the http: (non-secure) version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I could'nt find any informations on this, but have you tried playing sound from Javascript ? I don't know if it's a viable workaround for you but this might be a solution.
You can find different ways to do it here: http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play.htm

Hope that will help you.

Comment: The problem is that the solution should work without JavaScript, this was given as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to your comment to jamesh, I would advise to provide instead a link to the audio file: some computers (mine at work) have no sound, not everybody is using IE, embed isn't part of HTML (it is a hack supported by various browsers, it isn't defined in [HTML 4.01 Transitional DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/loosedtd.html) for example) and chances are the visiting browser have no plug-in to play your sound.

As your tests show, it is prone to problems...

At worst, provide a `<NOEMBED>` tag to supply the said link. Or nest various methods, like `<object>`. At least, Flash is supported by nearly all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the way, browsers changed operations like using flash and playing audio. I have tried java, html  embeded code none is exact.. the only thing i noticed is if you make a link on another page to the page that suppose to play the music it will work every time. but many times it wont play if you take and put your music page url in url box.. the link is reliable to the music page..  Don't know why?
I have been working for a while on it. and of course there the difference between all the various browsers.  The embedded code embed src='https://server.com/path-to-sound' hidden="true" autostart="true" />you showed before should work as long a sound file is there and if placed as first line after body statement.